# Access to Custom UITableViewCell UILabel Text in Swift throws error

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell, including my own UILabel inside.

I've created a single view application with Swift, and added a Cocoa Touch Class with .xib file, than I add the UILabel and create an Outlet in the new file(CustomCell Class).

In the main StoryBoard I've added a UITableView, and initialize it with data (implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate).

When I'm trying to access to the text property in the UILabel, it fail with that error:

> fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

This is my CustomCell Class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var myLbl: UILabel

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func SetValue(value: String){
        myLbl.text = value  // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Here is the code the creates the cells in the main ViewController:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{
        var cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Default")
        cell.SetValue(stringArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because myLbl is nil.

That is because you are not creating your cell using your Nib. You are using init with style. What you should do, is register the nib with the table view and then use deque on the tableview:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var cellNib = UINib(nibName:"ANibName", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "default")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("default", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CutomCell
    cell.SetValue(stringArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell;
}
```

If, however, you are creating template cells in the Nib for your view controller, you don't have to register the seperate Nib for the cell but you still need to deque the cell like above.

Comment: Its looks like he is attached OK, I see the circle in the left side of the editor next to IBOutlet line. (the circle is gray)

Comment: Then are you sure you are actually loading it from the nib? How are you creating the cell?

Comment: Question updated. but I'm pretty sure its not the problem. if I'm creating the cell in the same way but without the UILabel.text, its works fine.

Comment: @user3210784 Ok, I updated my answer. You are not loading your cell from a nib, you are just creating it programmatically

Comment: It's working, but now I have other error: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11675D3B-7030-4DC5-8D7A-2D2693DAE3EE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D08FDC90-6F4F-4D21-95FA-0C5DBCF5B0E8/TableViewCellsTest.app> (loaded)' with name 'ANibName''

Comment: @user3210784 do you have a separate Nib for your cell? I used "ANibName" as an example, you need to change that to the name of your Nib.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, change ANibName to CustomCell. And still same error like I wrote in the main question.